# Split dataframes within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, xts

I was wondering how to split several data frames contained on a list.
I have a list with 200 data frames, each one containing two columns, Price and Volume. I would like to split it and have one list with 200 df of Price and another list with 200 df of Volume.

Thanks

Comment: `lapply(MYLIST, function(a) a[,1])` and `lapply(MYLIST, function(a) a[,2]) `

Comment: @d.b that works, but it returns the first row, not column. Any idea on how to change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, using `base R` only. Tested with the dataset in the answer by Moody_Mudskipper.

```
lapply(your_list, '[[', "Price")
lapply(your_list, '[[', "Volume")
```

**EDIT.**
Like Moody_Mudskipper says in his comment, in order to fully answer the question I should use `'['` and not `'[['`. The latter returns *vectors*, the former returns *sub-data.frames*. And the OP asks for "one list with 200 df of Price and another list with 200 df of Volume".

```
lapply(your_list, '[', "Price")
#[[1]]
#  Price
#1     3
#2     4
#
#[[2]]
#  Price
#1     3
#2     9
#
#[[3]]
#  Price
#1     7
#2     1
lapply(your_list, '[', "Volume")
# output ommited
```

Comment: then actually drop the second bracket and you'll get exactly what he was asking, which is to have lists of `data.frames`. I answered a bit fast as well and mimicked @d.b 's solution :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, you're right. I missed that point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `purrr::transpose`:

```r
set.seed(1)
your_list <- list(data.frame(Price = sample(10,2),Volume = sample(10,2)),
                  data.frame(Price = sample(10,2),Volume = sample(10,2)),
                  data.frame(Price = sample(10,2),Volume = sample(10,2)))
str(your_list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ Price : int [1:2] 3 4
#>   ..$ Volume: int [1:2] 6 9
#>  $ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ Price : int [1:2] 3 9
#>   ..$ Volume: int [1:2] 10 6
#>  $ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ Price : int [1:2] 7 1
#>   ..$ Volume: int [1:2] 3 2
str(purrr::transpose(your_list))
#> List of 2
#>  $ Price :List of 3
#>   ..$ : int [1:2] 3 4
#>   ..$ : int [1:2] 3 9
#>   ..$ : int [1:2] 7 1
#>  $ Volume:List of 3
#>   ..$ : int [1:2] 6 9
#>   ..$ : int [1:2] 10 6
#>   ..$ : int [1:2] 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat feature of `purrr` just for that

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
your_list <- list(data.frame(Price = sample(10,2),Volume = sample(10,2)),
     data.frame(Price = sample(10,2),Volume = sample(10,2)),
     data.frame(Price = sample(10,2),Volume = sample(10,2)))
# [[1]]
#   Price Volume
# 1     3      6
# 2     4      9
# 
# [[2]]
#   Price Volume
# 1     3     10
# 2     9      6
# 
# [[3]]
#   Price Volume
# 1     7      3
# 2     1      2
```

**Results**

```
library(purrr)
map(your_list,"Price")
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 9
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 7 1

map(your_list,"Volume")
# [[1]]
# [1] 6 9
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10  6
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 2
```